# SQLLDR rejecting some records while accepting others which have the same value

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I've been loading TSV files into our database for some time now using the same control file and there have been no issues until recently.

The control file looks somewhat like this (with actual table and column names omitted):

```
INTO TABLE "TABLE_NAME" WHEN RECORD_TYPE = 'TYPE'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY X'9'
TRAILING NULLCOLS
    (ID CONSTANT 'FILE_ID',
     FILE_NAME "'FILE_NAME'",
     IMPORT_START "SYSDATE",
     RECORD_TYPE POSITION(1),
     COLUMN_X,
     COLUMN_Y,
     COLUMN_Z,
    )
```

Where the `RECORD_TYPE` is the first value in the record. i.e.

`TYPE *TAB* COLUMN_X *TAB* COLUMN_Y *TAB* COLUMN_Z`

When I try to load a file it loads without any errors but discards **some** of a specific record type whilst loading most of them, giving me the following message in the log file:

> Record x: Discarded - failed all WHEN clauses.

I have poured over the file and cannot see anything wrong with the data.

I tried changing the order of the respective `INTO TABLE "TABLE_NAME" WHEN RECORD_TYPE` blocks so that the failing one was nearer to the top in a desperate attempt to see if it would make a difference and for some reason it worked.

This doesn't make any sense to me, since I have not changed the conditions for any of the WHEN clauses, only the order of them, so I shouldn't be failing **all** of them in either case... I'm wondering if anyone with better experience with SQLLDR will be able to shed some light on this strange behavior?

Comment: Can you post one record which was loaded and one which was not?

Comment: Look at the offending data file in an editor that allows you to view it in hex and see if you have other control characters in there that may be causing the problem.  Could be bad data that you just can't see. This happened to me once when our vendor sent unicode unexpectedly.  Looked just fine in my editor until I switched to hex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple INTO TABLE clauses work in a very unintuitive way. See [this Ask Tom post](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:3181887000346205200). What I think is happening is that the first INTO TABLE clause processes the line successfully, ending at the end of the line, and then the second INTO TABLE clause starts *in the same place*, doesn't find any characters at all because it's at the end of the line, so it fails the WHEN clause. See also [this documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97630_01/server.920/a96652/ch05.htm#1005856).

It sounds like you need to use the POSITION(1) argument for the first column in each INTO TABLE clause to tell it to start at the beginning of the line:

```
INTO TABLE "TABLE_NAME" WHEN RECORD_TYPE = 'TYPE'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY X'9'
TRAILING NULLCOLS
    (ID POSITION(1) "'FILE_ID'",
     FILE_NAME "'FILE_NAME'",
     IMPORT_START "SYSDATE",
     RECORD_TYPE POSITION(1),
     COLUMN_X,
     COLUMN_Y,
     COLUMN_Z,
    )
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this has fixed my problem and I've learned something valuable too!